# Current control circuit doesn't work in practice

Tags: mosfet

A control circuit works in simulation, but don't in real. What is my mistake? 
[image]

[image]

Current through R5 or Mosfet proportional with V1 voltage in linear region. But in practice even when V1=0, the current through R5 is more than 1A !!. Power supply limit the current consumption and the mosfet very hot.

BestRegards

EDIT

I changed the circuit after comments. 
[image]

This works similar to simulations. But MOSFET very hot even 0.5A through R5.   I can't give exact temperature degree. But it was very hot. 
Is this circuit structure ideal? Should I continue here?
I can connect heatsink if this circuit is best.

Comment: Are you really using a 741 or is that just the default for the opamp symbol and you're actually using something else?

Comment: Using the LM741 isn't recommended, it can only drive it's output to about 2 V from the supply rails. So for your 12 V supply that would mean 2 V to 10 V. That 2 V might not be enough to fully switch off the MOSFET. Also, the 741 cannot operate with input voltages close to the supply rails. When V1 = 0 V you're asking that poor 741 to do that anyway. It can't and might punish you by just making it's output high swichting on the MOSFET. Power the 741 with +12 V and - 12 V and then maybe it will work as intended. But a better solution is to use a better opamp.

Comment: Your control circuit is open-loop. Shouldn't you be taking the feedback from the top of R5 rather than from the output of the op-amp?

Comment: Yes, OPAMP is UA741. Why it works in simulation?

Comment: I use OPAMP for gain2. If feedback from top of R5, OPMAP also service a gain2?

Answer (score 2):

The 741 output cannot swing to the negative supply rail, so you'll always get a fair bit of current through the MOSFET (depending on the threshold voltage of the MOSFET you happen to have).

The inputs cannot respond down to the negative rail, and you should take the feedback from the 3.7\$\Omega\$ current sense resistor, so you're feeding back a voltage proportional to the current. You may not need R2, it may be better to just reduce R5 proportionally.

Using an LM358 or similar single-supply op-amp rather than a 741 and changing the circuit will help a lot, though there is still the possibility of oscillation (compensation for which has been dealt with frequently here).

It's a linear circuit and power dissipation is maximized when it's operating into a shorted load (load in this case is between +12 and the drain of the MOSFET). So you will get power dissipation in the MOSFET plus resistor of Iout * 12V.

If you want a current source with the load grounded, you'll have to use a more complex circuit that shifts the ground-referenced input voltage up to the 12V rail.

Note: There may be something else wrong with your circuit. Measure the Vgs and if it is less than about 3V you should not be getting 1A through the MOSFET. Maybe a connection issue or something else.

Comment: Yes, I need control current through SMA. R5 is a SMA wire in fact. I want to increase/decrease current proportional to input voltage. Could you advice another circuit?

Comment: What do you mean by SMA? The connector?

Comment: Sorry, Shape memory alloy.

Comment: How much does the resistance of the Nitinol or whatever change with temperature? You don't have a constant current circuit if it's dependent on R5 resistance. Have you considered a PWM circuit, which could run cool?

Comment: I also get feedback with sense resistor. This part hasn't showed in the figure. So I don't need constant current. I'm reading actual current then set V1 voltage as desired current. Now I have problem with over temperature of MOSFET.

Comment: Have you considered PWM?

Comment: Do you mean, if 2V need to specified current, i can drive 4V %50 duty PWM signal instead of 2V constant?

Comment: RMS current would be higher than your example but generally yes.